# Are there any changes in udev/rules.d syntax from RHEL6 to RHEL7?

Tags: linux, rhel, udev

Can local rules defined in RHEL6 be used as it is in RHEL7 or we need to do changes with respect to syntax before using them in RHEL7.

Answer (score 0):

On rackspace, centos 6 and 7 have the same

```
 md5sum /etc/udev/rules.d/z10-xen-vcpu-hotplug.rules
```

.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="cpu", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '[ ! -e. /sys$devpath/online ] || echo 1 > /sys$devpath/online'"
```